# Facebook API v2.2 incorrect endpoint response format?

Tags: facebook

The official Facebook Docs says following for API v2.2:

> All API endpoints will now always return valid JSON

But when I call this endpoint:

> https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/oauth/access_token

It returns a flat string instead of a JSON if successful:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
access_token=XXX&expires=5182351
```

But the same endpoint returns JSON if failed:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request 
...
{"error":{"message":"This authorization code has expired.","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}
```

Is it a bug in API or a mistake in the Docs?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds more like an oversight in semantics than anything.

The `oauth/access_token` is an entry point for the API, whereas the majority of other points that have graph.facebook.com as the base, consume the access token obtained from there.

i.e. `graph.facebook.com/{object}?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`

Filing a documenation bug would be the best way to find out for sure.

Comment: I'd also encourage you to open a documentation bug.

Comment: Documented bug is the feature :)

Comment: So, will this endpoint *always* return JSON in a next API version?